# How to make my JS variable global to stop being undefined?

Tags: javascript

When i'm trying to run this http://jsfiddle.net/854Ej/, that executes my code inside a

`$(window).load(function(){`
function its keep posting an undefined error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: _my_var is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the fiddle is running in window.onload so the variable is in a closure and it is not global.

```
window.onload = function() {
   var _my_var; //This is local
}
```

Either set the code to run at the bottom of the page or force the variable to be in window scope.

Comment: And how can I make it global? (dummy question :))

Comment: set the fiddle to run at the end of the body or use `window._trustvox = [];` or drop the `var`

Answer (score 0):

var _trustvox = _trustvox || [];

your above line won't work because you haven't set _trustvox to anything and you are attempting to use it.

do instead.

var _trustvox = [];

Use local storage if you want to retain variable content.

Comment: I already tried that and doesn't work either. Edit the fiddle and you'll see it :)